# How to get the right amount of payments still to receive?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an mysql query to get an total of invoice payments to receive:

```
SELECT
SUM(amount * ((vat / 100) + 1)) AS total
FROM invoices
WHERE status = 'send' AND date_paid = 0
```

I have an other table where the amounts received are stored. How to handle invoices that are partially paid so I can see the true amount to receive?
I'm using an table to store the payments called payments_rev and columns invoice_id and amount.

I have tried:

```
SELECT
SUM(amount * ((vat / 100) + 1)) AS total,
SUM(pd.amount) AS total_paid
FROM invoices AS inv
LEFT JOIN 11_invoices_paid AS pd
ON pd.inv_id = inv.id
WHERE inv.status = 'send' AND inv.date_paid = 0
GROUP BY inv.id
```

As result it gives total_paid = 0 ??

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoices` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dossier_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_no` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `amount_excl` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `vat` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `date_send` date NOT NULL,
  `date_pay` date NOT NULL,
  `date_paid` date NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoices_paid` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

)

Comment: You probably need to do a join on the the table with amounts received and invoices, but without knowing the columns in both tables. Couldn't even tell you if its possible.

Comment: table schema of both the tables?